# std::vector of objects and sorting results in segmentation faults

Tags: c++, sorting, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I been sitting over this problem quiet a few hours now and can not find a solution. I try to get rid of some Custom Array classes and want to change them to std::vector.

I have a class member declared like this:

```
std::vector<BaseCluster *> baseClusters;
```

In the class constructor I do not initialize the vector to a certain size. I leave it as is, uninitialized. Before, I tried to initialize if to a certain size (to gain some performance and prevent many reallocations), but that gave me problems accessing the elements in a loop (eg. printing them out). I guess it is due to the initialization of the objects with the default constructor (of type BaseCluster) as NULL-Objects ??

However, in a loop I fill the vector with objects like this

```
baseClusters.push_back(new BaseCluster(current, score));
```

After the loop finishes I do some cleanup of objects that are not interesting:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < baseClusters.size(); i++) {
    // --- testing   
    if (baseClusters.at(i) == NULL) {
       wcout << i << ". object is NULL" << endl;
    }
    if (
      ((BaseCluster *) baseClusters.at(i))->getNode()->getSuffixedDocumentsCount() < minimalGroupSize
    ) {
        baseClusters.erase(baseClusters.begin() + i);
    }

    if (i >= noMoreBaseClustersThan) {
        baseClusters.erase(baseClusters.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

Now I sort the vector (should be sorted by score descending) and here I have a problem:

1.) using the sort as

```
sort(baseClusters.begin(), baseClusters.end());
```

doesn't sort at all, also my implemented "operators<" or "operator>" in the BaseCluster class are not touched at all. The operators are public and look like this.

```
bool operator< (const BaseCluster * rhs) const {
    return m_score < rhs->m_score;
}

bool operator> (const BaseCluster * rhs) const {
    return m_score > rhs->m_score;
}
```

2.) Using a predicate / functor

```
class BaseClusterComparator {
public:
    bool operator() (const BaseCluster * a, const BaseCluster * b) const {
        wcout << "BaseClusterComparator" << endl;
        wcout << a->getScore() << " <> " << b->getScore() << endl;
        if (a->getScore() > b->getScore()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a->getScore() < b->getScore()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

the class member getScore looks like this

```
float
BaseCluster::getScore() const {
    return m_score;
}
```

and executing the sort with

```
sort(baseClusters.begin(), baseClusters.end()), BaseClusterComparator());
```

will result in an segmentation fault when trying to access the getScore() method after sorting about 60 - 70 objects.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004773ec in BaseCluster::getScore (this=0x2ef1) at algorithm/BaseCluster.cpp:44
44      return m_score;
```

I have the feeling that due to reserving / resizing of the vector there are NULL-objects (constructed with the default constructor of BaseClass ?!).

And now am stuck on how to solve the problem. What am I doing wrong here? I been reading through many other related stackoverflow questions before asking here, followed them by changing here and there but no way out of the seg. faults. As far as I am aware I do not insert any Null-Objects (tested that in the loop), so there must be another flaw in my code. Thought it was an quiet easy task changing to a vector of pointers, but seems more complicated now...

Please, anybody help me on this issue. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What makes you think that the default value of a pointer is NULL? It's whatever was in memory last before the pointer, so garbage essentially. Also, when `erase`ing objects, you should decrement `i` afterwards or you'll skip objects. And you need to make sure you don't exceed the bounds of the vector after erasing (you currently do more checks on the next element, which may not even exist). Also, -1 and 1 both evaluate to true -- your return value is wrong about half the time. As for the segfault: Double check that the pointers in your vector are all valid (and never pointing to freed memory).

Comment: @Cameron: You mean by inserting **i--** right after each erase call in the loop? NULL objects: I thought, initializing the vector as **std::vector<BaseCluster *>(1000)** for example, will initalize the contents of that vector with 1000 elements with the defined type (using the default constructor). First I thought it would be something like **BaseCluster *b = NULL** the vector gets initialized with in that way.

Comment: If I initialize the vector in the class constructor with with a size of 1000, I get a seg fault as soon as I want to access an element (after the vectors as been filled), if I initialize it with 0, there is no problem. Now I use **reserve()** and this seems to work.

Comment: As a side note: I changed that loop where I erase the elements into **EraseClusterIf eci(params); baseClusters.erase(std::remove_if(baseClusters.begin(), baseClusters.end(), eci), baseClusters.end())** using an predicate. That works way better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is wrong:

`std::sort` is not like qsort in the comparator. You just have to return the same as the less than operator. For example

```
class BaseClusterComparator {
public:
    bool operator() (const BaseCluster * a, const BaseCluster * b) const {
        return a->getScore() < b->getScore();
    }
};
```

Comment: yes, the comparator fct was "derived" from an qsort comparator used in the old Array classes. I just wonder why the operators in the BaseCluster class are not used when sort is called as **sort(baseClusters.begin(), baseClusters.end())**. At least this should have worked ... or not?

Comment: The operators from the class are not automatically used because the `vector` contains only pointers.  The default less-than is in terms of the actual contents of the `vector`.  The pointers would be compared by value, which is why your first attempt didn't seem to be sorted: you can't predict what the memory addresses will be.  If you fix your `BaseClusterComparator` class and use the 3-argument version of `sort()`, it will work.

Comment: @Kevin Grant: Thanks for the clarification. I was just wondering. I changed the comparators like JRB suggested and all works fine.